# Play framework model unit test

Tags: unit-testing, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

According to [Play's documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTodoList) the (MVC) model should look like this:

```
object MyModel {
    //code
}
```

How do you unit test this? In [Play's unit testing documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTest) the example model is no longer defined as an object, but a class instead. I've built my application declaring models as objects, does it mean I have to change that now?

This is an example of how controller object can be unit tested. This:

```
object MyController extends Controller {
}
```

has to be changed into this:

```
trait MyController {
   //code
}

object MyController extends Controller with MyController
```

in order for it to be unit testable, in which case the unit test will look something like this:

```
object MyControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification with Results {

    class TestController() extends Controller with MyController

    //unit test code

}
```

Do I have to / Can I apply the same technique to test my models (objects)? If so then how? If no then the only way is to have all the models as classes instead of objects?

Play Framework 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test objects and those objects themselves decides what their dependencies are and how to talk to them, the only way will be to somehow replace those dependencies, so for example with database access it could be providing a different config that runs against another database, this will require that you make sure that that database is kept clean inbetween test runs and does not leak data between test cases though. Another problem with it is that it may make your tests run slow.

If you rather would like to run unit tests that only test one specific piece of code, there is a bunch of variations on how you can do that using dependency injection. One example of simple depencency injection would be (aboutish what you described with your controllers):

```
class EntityDAO(db: SomeWayToTalkToADB) {
  ... defs using db ...
}

object EntityDao extends EntityDAO(Somwehere.concreteDBaccess)
```

And then in the tests:

```
"My entity dao" should {

  "do stuff with the db" in {
     val dao = new EntityDao(somefakeDB)
     dao.doStuff mustEqual something
  }
}
```

This way you could easily provide a fake implementation, a mock created with for example mockito etc.

Other options could be to provide the actual db access object in a second parameter list to each method that needs it, possibly implicit to avoid repeating yourself. You could also use the cake pattern, some DI-library or possibly monads depending on how deep you want to go into the functional stuff.

Comment: Note that if your controller did not have any dependencies that it calls you would not have to split it up into trait and object but could just call the object directly.